# CSS Flexbox - Child Elements Not Aligning Properly giving unequal spacing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm using CSS Flexbox to create a layout with multiple child elements. However, I'm encountering an issue where the child elements are not aligning properly within the parent container. I want them to be evenly distributed and centered horizontally, but they appear misaligned or with unequal spacing.

**My code is:**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">box 1</div>
  <div class="child">box 2</div>
  <div class="child">box 3</div>
</div>
```

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

What could be causing this issue? How can I ensure that the child elements are evenly distributed and centered within the parent container using CSS Flexbox? Give Any insights or suggestions Please.

Creating space on the left side and evenly distributing any remaining space between the elements. The expected outcome is that the child elements should be evenly distributed and centered both horizontally and vertically within the parent container.

Comment: What do you mean by OR, Raj? the result is different each time you open the html file or what? That's hard to see the issue without any illustration between the actual behavior and the expected one.

Comment: NOW In result these 3 divs coming in center but i want to use full of width and only want to show these 3 divs content . In Short, in Final Result 3 divs have same width but use 100% of width wihout any other div coming with these. please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to center child item horizontally and vertically with equal space between then align in center. Here is code you can try this.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-item: center;
  gap: 1rem; /* Adjust according to your need*/
}

.child{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">box 1</div>
     <div class="child">box 2</div>
     <div class="child">box 3</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: No any changes in result,NOW In result these 3 divs coming in center but i want to use all present area.

Comment: use justify-content: space-evenly;

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear what you expect to happen, but you have not set a width for each child, if you want full 100% they need to be 33.3% here set to 30

```css
#parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#parent > div {
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.child{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">box 1</div>
  <div class="child">box 2</div>
  <div class="child">box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
/* Distributed alignment */
justify-content: space-between; /* Distribute items evenly
                                   The first item is flush with the start,
                                   the last is flush with the end */

justify-content: space-around; /* Distribute items evenly
                                   Items have a half-size space
                                   on either end */

justify-content: space-evenly; /* Distribute items evenly
                                   Items have equal space around them */
```

You should checkout MDN for more flex justify properties here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34599018)

Comment: @SangwinGawande alright I'll keep it in mind from next time. Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `align-items` to parent:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.child {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```